# Jmeter Regression test

Tags: rest, jmeter

I am new to stackoverflow.

I have an app that i would like to test over night with jmeter and having trouble to do so.

Im sending a restapi call that triggers a flow.

I would like to create a test in jmeter (already created) that will send a json in a scheduled time and will send the same json when the process is done (after getting the response)

I Have a Thread Group with an HTTP Request + HTTP Header Manager + View Results Tree.

Some guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work? Can you show us any code you have that we can work from?

Comment: Please detail the problem that you are facing. Where are you stuck? Have you validated the HTTP request? Have you manually created the request or captured it via proxy by some means from the app? Elaborate on the problem so that we can help you out and screenshots of your current work on JMeter will do loads of good to us. It'll help us have an idea about what you have tried and the remaining options available.

Comment: Sorry guys but i cant yet post images (i think i need more reputation).

Hi guys , Thanks for the responses.
So far i have build my thread groups and HTTP Requests:

Answer (score 0):

Thread Group also provides a scheduler. Click the checkbox at the bottom of the Thread Group panel to enable/disable extra fields in which you can enter the duration of test .

You can use the two other fields Start time and End time. When the test is started, JMeter will wait if necessary until the start-time has been reached.

You can define you start and end time per day. but this jmx need to be updated daily.